# rootkits subverting the windows kernel source code

Tags: source-code, websites

I just purchased the book "rootkits: subverting the windows kernel" by Greg Hoglund and James Butler for a research project at work.
However, this book constantly refers to the source code that can be downloaded at rootkit.com, a site that has been taken down apparently after a compromise a few years back.

Anyone any idea where I could get the code that accompanies the book? (a legitimate trustworthy source of course, not some kind of shady underground forum or tor-site or whatever).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Should you really be trusting a security book who'so website got compromised to the point where it is no longer online ? ... P.s. The publishers phone number is going to be in the book somewhere , ring them. In my experience you should be able to order the supplemental data on cdrom

Comment: I don't see the relevance of your remark. They compromised the website using social engineering, which kind of says nothing about the technical security behind the entire setup. Plus, what do rootkits have to do with securing a website? Anyways, thanks for replying to my question.

Comment: Some one in China hosts a big source-code repo which happens to contain some(maybe all) source code from this book, but you need to pay a bit to download it. http://www.codebus.net/d-G1PG.html Good luck.